# Updated AWS SDK and now getting presigned errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, java

I've just upgraded to the lastest Java SDK and my presigned urls are no longer working.

Previously I used

```
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter(
                Headers.S3_CANNED_ACL,
                CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead.toString()
        );
```

However now the generatePresignedUrlRequest returns this error:

```
There were headers present in the request which were not signed:  x-amz-acl
```

How do I sign the x-amz-acl header?

Answer (score 1):

Changed to:

```
   generatePresignedUrlRequest.putCustomRequestHeader(Headers.S3_CANNED_ACL, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead.toString());
```

Comment: Good that you found a solution! Consider marking your answer as accepted if it completely addresses the problem.